# Android Studio 3.1 canary 8 cannot stop at breakpoints on Junit Tests

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Just as the title says, I'm unable to stop on breakpoints while trying to debug JUnit tests.

The only visual cue that I get is when the debugger attach, all my breakpoints are shown with an "x"

Is this a known issue with this version? Or do I have to make extra steps to make it work?

Update:

Ok, what I found is that the tests that are on JAVA they can be stopped by any breakpoint, but when the breakpoint is set on Kotlin classes (that are called on my java tests) they don't work. And when the test is on Kotlin, the breakpoints doesn't work at all...

Comment: Known issue, reported on the official issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72192685. 

We will have to wait for a fix within the next version.

As a workaround, to debug, I write a very small test in a Java class. In this one I can put a breakpoint (which will work), then I go to my Kotlin code with the step by step.

Comment: This was fixed a few days ago so hopefully, we'll see it in AS soon. As a workaround, you can [take the steps outlined here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22205#u=1515626373406) to prevent a build from occurring before the test runs.